# Preventing a determined user from directly editing linked tables

Tags: sql-server, security, ms-access

I built an Access db which has a SQL Server backend. I have a stubborn and somewhat knowledgable user who will often go into the tables directly. I am attempting to stop this behavior.

The issue I am having is because he is a legitimate user of the database I had to give him read/write access to SQL Server so he could use the db like everyone else. However, no matter how I compile or hide panels at the end of the day all he has to do is open a new blank Access db, use his ODBC connection, link to the SQL Server backend using linked tables, and poof his read-write access allows him to edit tables directly.

Is there some way for me to give users read only or better yet No access what so ever to the SQL Server tables and still have the db function properly? "Properly" meaning users can make record changes like edit comments etc. Sort of like how a website works. The site itself has write access to the backend database and the user is just allowed to make changes using the GUI while on the site.

Comment: This is a perfect example of the limits of Access as an enterprise application.

Comment: Do you use Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication?

Comment: Is it possible to (in your access db) to read data from a SQL server view (grant select access to view) and save data through a stored procedure (grant execute)?

Comment: Seems like a people problem, not a technical one.

Comment: Remove write access and wait for problem to escalate.

Comment: "Sort of like how a website works. The site itself has write access to the backend database and the user is just allowed to make changes using the GUI while on the site" - except with Access, this is "have the user install the website on  a web server under their control"

Comment: We use Windows authentication and Damien you're right it is a people problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solveable only with significant application changes.

You could redesign your application to only use Stored Procedure for data access. No user (at least not the nasty one) has write permission on any table in your database. Every write operation is done via Stored Procedures.

This is a tried and proven approach to securing databases. However, it is used less nowadays because it requires extra efforts to make it work with OR-Mappers and other RAD-Tools like Access. If you implement this approach in an Access Frontend, you’ll have to implement every write operation to the database manually and thus are losing the main RAD advantage of Access.

*Why is this user editing data in tables a problem?*

If your database has a solid set of validation rules implemented with Constraints and Triggers and has proper auditing in place to know which user changed what, then this should not be a problem. You just let him do it, if he wants to.

***But why is the user doing this at all?***

If any user rather uses backend tables directly to read and write data, this indicates a massive usability problem with your application. **Address the usability issues in your frontend application** and the problem will go away while benefiting all of your users!

---

PS: The concept of application roles, which could be another approach to address this problem, does not work with Access. Access creates new connections to the database on its own. There is no possibility to activate the application role for these connections.

Comment: "If your database has a solid set of validation rules implemented with Constraints and Triggers and has proper auditing in place to know which user changed what, then this should not be a problem. You just let him do it, if he wants to." - except for one thing (unless it's changed in recent versions) - when you open the table editor in Access, it takes rather unfriendly locks on the tables, potentially preventing other users from performing any insert/update/delete.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Good point! That is indeed an issue that will remain. And no, that has not changed in recent versions of Access.

Comment: I have other Access databases that use ADO connection baked into VBA and the users are completely locked out of the SQL Server tables. However, I ran into a problem on this one where I had to use a continuous form and couldn't try as I might to successfully use that same ADO connection to work properly. Do you know if continuous forms use Stored Procedures?

Comment: Yes, you can use a Stored Procedure as Recordsource of a continuous form. But it gets difficult to handle the updates. By default Access will analyze the recordset returned from the SP and then write directly to the table(!). - So nothing gained regarding you problem there. You need to return a data from a temp table and write the modified rows to the real table on close of the form.

Answer (score 0):

> I had to give him read/write access to SQL Server so he could use the
>   db like everyone else

You can't both give him access and not.

The only way out is speaking to management to ask for formal rules and to tell users to follow these and behave.

Comment: He is management and I've tried addressing it with his superiors. I have to stop him with the application.

Comment: Ah, then it can turn difficult. You should take care of regular backups then and, whenever he has done some damage, claim that the database has to be restored.

Answer (score 0):

Get your IT department to uninstall Access, install the Access Runtime and have him use your application that way.